# Python read text file performance

Tags: python-3.x

I have 6 Gb text file, 18 columns separate each other by TAB delimiter for a total rows of about 16 million, example:

```
david   23457   lola    98.341  ...     column18
freeze  954     mike    34.15   ...     column18
...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...
...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...
david   ...     ...     ...     ...     row 16milion
```

I use Python 3 64 bit and my hardware is: 8GB ram, i7-5500U 2,4GHz and win 7 64bit. I try to understand which is the fastest way to read the file and compare each value of first column to a string but unfortunally the best time was about 1 minute. I try to understand why is to slow and I discover that only to read the entire file with a pass instruction take something about 50 seconds (CPU or RAM are not use so much: 25%CPU and 2GB ram in windows task manager). This is the code to test the speed of reading:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt

t1=dt.now()
f1=open('6Gb file.txt', 'r')
for line in f1:
    pass
f1.close()        
t2=dt.now()
print(t2-t1)
```

If I try to compare each value of first column with a string of my choice (it is possible find duplicate value in columns) and if match write the entire row in a new file. The total process take about 1 minutes, so in take only about 10 seconds more:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt

t1=dt.now()
f2=open('newfile.txt', 'w')
f1=open('6Gb file.txt', 'r')
for line in f1:
    line=line.split('   ')
    if(line[0]=='freeze'):
        for i in line[:-1]:
            f2.write(i+'    ')
        for i in line[-1:]:       
            f2.write(i)
f1.close()
f2.close()
t2=dt.now()
print(t2-t1)
```

Is it possible speed up the reading?

Comment: 6gigs in 60 seconds == 1 gig per 10 seconds == ~100mb/sec. Do research on throughput of harddrive..is 100mb/s fast, slow, average? Perhaps the drive is the limiting factor?

Comment: Since you have enough RAM, you can profile how fast it is to read everything to memory (or half the file) using iteration or using `f.read()`. What happens if you open it with `rb`?

Comment: HDD is 2TB 5400RPM

Comment: And, of course, it should be faster to do it in C or with a dedicated utility written in C (which is not CPython). I once got a 2000x boost this way - in a very different setting though.

Comment: I try to use f.read (not all in memory because is to big) but it wasn't more fast. I try also with chunks in pandas and the time  process was 2 minutes!

Comment: I try with a computer with SSD samsung 830, same code above. Result was about 10 seconds better to read... 40 seconds. Still is a big time.

People tell me that with AWK (in linux) this kind of process take only few seconds (simple reading or also filter by a value). So the limitation was the OS or Python?